# Checking whole string with a regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to check if a string is a number, so the regex "\d+" seemed good. However that regex also fits "78.46.92.168:8000" for some reason, which I do not want, a little bit of code:

```
class Foo():
    _rex = re.compile("\d+")
    def bar(self, string):
         m = _rex.match(string)
         if m != None:
             doStuff()
```

And doStuff() is called when the ip adress is entered. I'm kind of confused, how does "." or ":" match "\d"?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`\d+` matches any positive number of digits **within** your string, so it matches the first `78` and succeeds.

Use `^\d+$`.

Or, even better: `"78.46.92.168:8000".isdigit()`

Comment: `\d+$` should be sufficient with match

Comment: `$` doesn't work in the case of a trailing newline. See `re.match(r'^\d+$', '4\n')` for example.

Comment: what does the the `$` and `^` do?

Comment: @CharlieParker: `^` matches the start of a line and `$` matches the end.

Answer (score 24):

There are a couple of options in Python to match an entire input with a regex.

## Python 2 and 3

In Python 2 and 3, you may use

```
re.match(r'\d+$') # re.match anchors the match at the start of the string, so $ is what remains to add
```

or - to avoid matching before the final `\n` in the string:

```
re.match(r'\d+\Z') # \Z will only match at the very end of the string
```

Or the same as above with `re.search` method requiring the use of `^` / `\A` start-of-string anchor as it does not anchor the match at the start of the string:

```
re.search(r'^\d+$')
re.search(r'\A\d+\Z')
```

Note that `\A` is an unambiguous string start anchor, its behavior cannot be redefined with any modifiers (`re.M` / `re.MULTILINE` can only redefine the `^`  and `$` behavior).

## Python 3

All those cases described in the above section and one more useful method, [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) (also present in the [PyPi `regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/)):

> If the whole *string* matches the regular expression *pattern*, return a corresponding match object. Return `None` if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

So, after you compile the regex, just use the appropriate method:

```
_rex = re.compile("\d+")
if _rex.fullmatch(s):
    doStuff()
```

Comment: do you need the `r` at the beginning of the regex?

Comment: @Charlie It is not required, but I'd use `re.compile(r"\d+")`

Comment: A note for all future visitors: it is a good idea NOT to omit the anchors even when using `re.fullmatch`. If your pattern must match the entire string, it is a good idea to keep the logic inside the pattern, since there may be scenarios with porting the pattern to other modules (like, e.g. Pyspark) where the regex functions are different and do not allow such flexibility.

Answer (score 14):

[`re.match()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) always matches from the start of the string (unlike [`re.search()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search)) but allows the match to end before the end of the string.

Therefore, you need an anchor: `_rex.match(r"\d+$")` would work.

To be more explicit, you could also use `_rex.match(r"^\d+$")` (which is redundant) or just drop `re.match()` altogether and just use `_rex.search(r"^\d+$")`.

Comment: do you need the `r` at the beginning of the regex?

Answer (score 8):

`\Z` matches the end of the string while `$` matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string, and exhibits different behaviour in `re.MULTILINE`. See [the syntax documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for detailed information.

```
>>> s="1234\n"
>>> re.search("^\d+\Z",s)
>>> s="1234"
>>> re.search("^\d+\Z",s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb762ed40>
```

Answer (score 5):

Change it from `\d+` to `^\d+$`