# Python regex to see if multiple words are contained in a string

Tags: python, regex

How do I construct a regex to see if any of the multiple words provided are contained in a string in python?

I've tried the below, but it matches words that contain the string. I only want to match whole words.

```
re.match("(one|two|three)", search_string, re.IGNORECASE)
```

With the above, words like `clone` would provide a match. However, I would like an exact match (e.g. `one`).

Comment: With multiple lookaheads and word boundaries.

Comment: `re.search(r"\b(one|two|three)\b", search_string, re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: @Wiktor: I guess, he rather wanted **multiple words** to be present in the string.

Comment: @Jan: *I only want to match whole words.* If a whole *string* is meant - [*Checking whole string with a regex*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994493/checking-whole-string-with-a-regex)

Comment: Is [**`^(?=.*\bone\b)(?=.*\btwo\b).+$`**](https://regex101.com/r/gB2rN9/1) what you're looking for?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you. I tried multiple permutations and needed the `"r"`among other things.

Comment: Aha, that means that the real duplicate is [*Does Python re module support word boundaries (\b)?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995034/does-python-re-module-support-word-boundaries-b)