# How to force regex to check on whole line

Tags: python, regex

Link: [Regexr](http://regexr.com/3gaf0)

Pattern: `\/activities\/\d{1,10}`

My problem is I want to match only lines like this:

```
/activities/1072361291
```

I don't want to match only part of line, with some additional characters on the end.
To be clear, that string: `/activities/1072361291#kudos`  shouldn't match pattern

Is it possible to do this with regex?

Comment: anchors `^/activities/1072361291$`

Comment: Work like a charm, thanks

Comment: Or `\A/activities/1072361291\Z`, might be better. Or just use [`re.fullmatch` in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44980529/3832970).