# Regex clarification (both return true?) powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to match a pattern in powershell, any 3 letters followed by any 2 numbers, example: abc00

Trying:

```
'abc00' -match '[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}'
```

returns TRUE

but :

```
'abcdefg0000' -match '[a-zA-Z]{3}[_0-9]{2}'
```

also returns TRUE.

How do I limit it so if the string doesn't contain exactly 3 letters and 3 numbers, it returns false?

Thank you!

Comment: Surround it with `^$` or `\b`: `^[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2}$` or `\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2}\b`. Also, don't post the same question multiple times. At least you deleted your old question, but try to only post it once.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994493/checking-whole-string-with-a-regex

Comment: also, whats the deal with the underscore ('_')?

Comment: ctwheels, thanks. I deleted my previous questions as i felt it was unclear but i should've edited it. Thank you.