# Regex for similar string

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have a string which can be :

```
X=Y
```

or

```
X
```

Here X and Y can be any word containing alphabets.

I want that when string is `X=Y` then X should in group 1 and Y in group 2

but when string is `X` then X should be in group 2.

So far I am able to get only this :

```
(\w+)=(\w+)
```

What should be the right regex for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match alphabets, you need to use `[a-zA-Z]` (to match any ASCII letter) or `[^\W\d_]` (this matches any Unicode letter), not `\w` that matches letters, digits or underscores and some more chars by default in Python 3.x.

You need

```
^(?:([A-Za-z]+)=)?([A-Za-z]+)$
```

Or

```
^(?:([A-Za-z]+)=)?([A-Za-z]+)\Z
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/20biL7/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:([A-Za-z]+)=)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `([A-Za-z]+)`  - Group 1: one or more letters
  - `=` - a `=` char
- `([A-Za-z]+)` - Group 2: one or more letters
- `\Z` - the very end of string (`$` matches the end of string position).

Comment: The most complete explanation. However, I would say that `$` matches the very end of string *and* any newline that appears immediately before it: `re.findall('$', 'abc\n')` -> `['', '']`

Comment: @Booboo You are using `re.findall` that searches for multiple match occurrences, that is why you have two matches :). Using `re.search` will yield the first match only.

Comment: I am using `findall` just to demonstrate what `$` matches. From the manual concerning `$`: **Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches before a newline.**

Comment: @Booboo That is why I posted two options and explained them in my answer. Also, mentioned in [Checking whole string with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994493/checking-whole-string-with-a-regex/44980529#44980529)

Comment: Nowhere in your distinction was the word *newline* mentioned. That's all I am saying.

Comment: @Booboo It is a known fact. That is the only distinction between "the end of string" and "the very end of string".

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it with your original regex.

It just needs a couple of tweaks:

```
^(\w+)(=(\w+))?$
```

- `^` = start of string
- `(\w+)` = 1st capture group matching any word like character (including numbers) as many times as possible.
- `(=...)?` = everything inside this 2nd capture group (starting with "=") is optional
- 2nd `(\w+)` = 3rd capture group matching the same stuff as the first one
- `$` = end of string

**update**

My answer does not actually answer the original question because the "X" string does not land "X" in the second answer group.

I considered deleting the answer, but I'm going to keep it up for the sake of other visitors on the site who are looking for a simpler answer that does not require "X" to specifically be in the second capture group.

Also, maybe the original asker would rather have a simpler regex and modify their code to work with the regex instead of making a regex to work with the code.

Comment: The answer is wrong because the `X` in `X` string [will land in Group 1](https://regex101.com/r/1cToxY/1), while OP wants it in Group 2.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an explanation why I think the answer is still useful even though it doesn't fullfill 100% of the original askers requirements.

Comment: Other users will probably find another answer already useful enough  at [How do I make part of a regex match optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12451749/3832970). If it was just about that, I would have closed the question as its duplicate.