# Regex match capturing group n times

Tags: python, regex

Looking for a way to match a pattern exactly n times.
For example, the following pattern matches the string 's4':

```
s4='123.45    67.891  0.234   5678.90'
re.match(r'\s*\d+\.\d*',s4)
Out[167]: <re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='123.45'>
```

But it will also match the strings 's3' and 's5':

```
s3='123.45    67.891  0.234'
s5='123.45    67.891  0.234   5678.90     12.34'
```

How to match only when the pattern is repeated exactly 4 times?
The "match exactly quantifier" {4} greedy or {4}? lazy will not match 's3' but will still match 's5' and put the 4th occurrence in the first capturing group:

```
re.match(r'(\s*\d+\.\d*){4}',s5)
Out[165]: <re.Match object; span=(0, 33), match='123.45    67.891  0.234   5678.90'>

re.match(r'(\s*\d+\.\d*){4}',s5).group(1)
Out[166]: '   5678.90'
```

Not understanding Regex.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe just use `matches = re.findall(r'\s*\d+\.\d*', string)` and then check `len(matches)`?

Comment: Just add boundaries https://regex101.com/r/HZ3vck/1

Comment: @Wiktor, this question may well be a dup of an earlier question but it bears no resemblance to the earlier question you cited, which was to determine if a string is comprised of one or more digits and nothing else. (Note selected answer.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland It seems as if OP just missed the point that `re.match` itself does not ensure the whole string match. The thread closed with deals exactly with that. Also, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44980529/3832970) explains that in detail. Accepted answers are not always the best answers, BTW.

Comment: @Wiktor, anyone looking to match a string a specified number of times may come upon this question as a result of a search and then go the linked earlier question for which this is a dup, where they will reach a dead end. We will agree to disagree on this one. I've voted to re-open.

Comment: @CarySwoveland This is a notorious duplicate. Do not reopen evident duplicates.

Comment: @Wiktor, as I said, "this may well be a dup", but if it's closed for that reason we should cite an earlier question that may be helpful to readers who have similar problems to the OP's.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That was exactly that: to match n times and not n+1, one must match the entire string.

Comment: @Wiktor, yes, match the whole string, but not check if the string contains nothing other than digits.

Comment: @CarySwoveland And as  mentioned, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44980529/3832970) shows it all.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following regular expression:

```
^(?:\s*(?:[1-9]|0(?=\.))\d*(?:\.\d+)?){4}\s*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/I2TPfC/1/)

If the regex matches the string the substrings representing numbers can be extracted by splitting the string on one or more spaces.

If integers are not permitted (only floats), remove the question mark from `(?:\.\d+)?`.

The following strings are not matched, for the reasons given:

```
123.45    67.891  0.234
  # too few numbers
123.45    67.891  0.234   5678.90     12.34
  # too many numbers
123.45   .67.891  22      5678.90
  # .67.891 is incorrect
123.45   067.891  22      5678.90
  # 067.891 contains a leading zero 
123.45      .891  0.234   5678.90
  # .891 requires a leading zero to be correct
```

If it is desired that either of the last two examples be matched the regex could be adjusted according.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^              # match beginning of string
  (?:          # begin non-cap grp
    \s*        # match 0+ spaces 
    (?:        # begin non-cap grp
      [1-9]    # match a digit other than zero
      |        # or
      0        # match 0
      (?=\.)   # match '.' in positive lookahead
    )          # end non-cap grp
    \d*        # match 0+ digits
    (?:\.\d+)  # match '.' followed by 1+ digits in non-cap grp
    ?          # optionally match non-cap grp
  )            # end non-cap grp
  {4}          # execute non-cap grp 4 times
  \s*          # match 0+ spaces
  $            # match end of line
```

Answer (score -1):

```
re.match(r'^(\s*\d+\.\d*){4}$',s5)
```

`$` at the end of the regexp makes it match to the end of the string.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
^(?:\d+\.\d+(?:[ ]+|$)){4}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nko0xF/2/)